# How to rotate the text of heading and font color google sheets api

Tags: php, api, format

Today i have made a dynamic google sheets as i want to rotate the text of heading how can i rotate heading text so please help me so that i can improove more.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC0WR.png)

Comment: what do you mean by "rotate" the text ? (rotate 90 degree / 180 degree ? )

Comment: Yes please i want to rotate in 90 degree

Answer (score 0):

For rotation, you can use the "setTextRottation" function:

```
// Sets the cells in the ranges A1:A10 and C1:C10 to have text rotated up 90 degrees.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['A1:A10', 'C1:C10']);
rangeList.setTextRotation(90);
```

Please refer to the following link for further documentation

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setTextRotation(Integer)